# Send whatsapp massage from Twilio using my number

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I want to send an invitation for an event using Twilio API using my own number.
It will be very good if the "log" of the messages will be also saved in my phone.

Is it possible to do it with the API? 
Sadly it seemed to be possible only after updating, so I've updated and paid the money and now I see that it's not that easy. The API is very confusing.

How can I do it?
When I write my number at the "From" I get:

```
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record: Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address
```

Is it possible to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about sending a message from your own phone number (your cell phone), this can not be done with Twilio.

From the [Twilio docs:](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133967-Change-the-From-number-or-Sender-ID-for-Sending-SMS-Messages)

> Note: You can not spoof messages from your own cell phone number. The From parameter can only display a Twilio number on your project, or an Alphanumeric Sender ID (where available).

Comment: Hi, Robert can you help me, is there any way I can program or use any API to send Whatsapp messages from my number?